# NiFi, Jolt's operation "substring" doesn't work

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have some datetime marks, and what I pretend is to group it in the quarter of hour just before it.

I have, e.g., this data:

```
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "dateTime": "2020-07-08T08:49:50+02:00",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "dateTime": "2020-07-08T13:14:57+02:00",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "dateTime": "2020-07-08T13:15:15+02:00",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "dateTime": "2020-07-08T13:36:39+02:00",
    "value": "1"
  }
]
```

After some JOLT Transformations, I have this data:

```
[ {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T08",
  "minutes" : "45",
  "value" : "1"
}, {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T13",
  "minutes" : "0",
  "value" : "1"
}, {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T13",
  "minutes" : "15",
  "value" : "1"
}, {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T13",
  "minutes" : "30",
  "value" : "1"
} ]
```

here, I have a problem. With the webpage http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/, I have managed to convert that "0" in "00" with the following JOLT code

```
[
{ "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta", 
  "spec": { 
    "*": { 
      "minutes": "=concat('0',@(0))" 
    } 
  } 
},
{ "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta", 
  "spec": { 
    "*": { 
      "minutes": "=substring(@(1,minutes),1,3)" 
    }
  }
}
]
```

Expected output (and achived with the webpage):

```
[ {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T08",
  "minutes" : "45",
  "value" : "1"
}, {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T13",
  "minutes" : "00",
  "value" : "1"
}, {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T13",
  "minutes" : "15",
  "value" : "1"
}, {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T13",
  "minutes" : "30",
  "value" : "1"
} ]
```

Real output in NiFi:

```
[ {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T08",
  "minutes" : "045",
  "value" : "1"
}, {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T13",
  "minutes" : "00",
  "value" : "1"
}, {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T13",
  "minutes" : "015",
  "value" : "1"
}, {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T13",
  "minutes" : "030",
  "value" : "1"
} ]
```

For some reason, "=substring()" function doesn't work as I expected in NiFi. Does anyone have any knack to take the last 2 items of the string?

Comment: I'm not able to update NiFi's version. Its version is 1.7.0 and so do the processor

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to number and leftPad it. See if it helps

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "minutes": ["=toInteger", 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "minutes": "=toString"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "minutes": "=leftPad(@(1,minutes),2,'0')"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Input:

```
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "dateHour": "2020-07-08T08",
    "minutes": "045",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "dateHour": "2020-07-08T13",
    "minutes": "00",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "dateHour": "2020-07-08T13",
    "minutes": "015",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "dateHour": "2020-07-08T13",
    "minutes": "030",
    "value": "1"
  }
]
```

output:

```
[ {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T08",
  "minutes" : "45",
  "value" : "1"
}, {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T13",
  "minutes" : "00",
  "value" : "1"
}, {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T13",
  "minutes" : "15",
  "value" : "1"
}, {
  "id" : "123",
  "dateHour" : "2020-07-08T13",
  "minutes" : "30",
  "value" : "1"
} ]
```

Comment: That function works in http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception, but not in NiFi 1.7.0 :( 
Thanks for your help